# Problem with methods of a doubly linked list

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have been trying to create (I have been learning it) a doubly linked list based on an exercise, in which the list will be train with wagons. The exercise asks to create a class "wagon" with the attributes "name of wagon", "next wagon" and "previous wagon", and another class "train" with the methods to add wagons, print the wagons and sawp the order of the locomotives of the trains. My problem is in how the exercise asks to create the method to add wagons, and the one to swap the order of the locomotives. The method to add wagons has a parameter that has as data type the class "wagon", and I have really not gotten to create this method. I am going to show you what I have already done in the code below. Could anyone help me with that? I have not understood how to use the parameter "vagaoCriar" in the method.

Besides that, the exercise asks to create two trains (then two lists), and to change the two locomotives of the two trains. I would like to know if that is really possible with two doubly linked lists, to swap two elements of them between themselves, or could it be simply swapping the order of the two doubly linked lists, without having to change elements between them? Because I have already searched it enough and I have not found anything saying that it is possible to swap elements between two doubly linked lists. Still, I have had some problem to create the method to swap the locomotives of the train, because the method has as data type "wagon", but it has as parameter "name of wagon" (String), and the name of the method is "get wagon and remove", so I do not have idea what the exercise really wishes.

I understand that the questions is long, but for such a complex example (for me), I could not be concise.

```
public class Vagao {
  String nomeDoVagao;
  Wagon vagaoAnterior;
  Wagon vagaoPosterior;

public Vagao (String nomeDoVagao){
  this.nomeDoVagao = nomeDoVagao;
  vagaoAnterior = null;
  vagaoPosterior = null;
 }
}

public class Trem {
  Vagao head, tail = null;

//I do not know to proceed here
public void adicionarVagao (Vagao vagaoCriar){
  Vagao novo_Vagao = new Vagao (vagaoCriar.nomeDoVagão);

  if (head == null){
    head = tail = novo_Vagao;
    head.vagaoAnterior = null;
    tail.vagaoPosterior = null;
} else {
    tail.vagaoPosterior = novo_Vagao;
    novo_Vagao.vagaoAnterior = tail;
    tail = novo_Vagao;
    tail.vagaoPosterior = null;
  }
 }

//This is the other method, that I have not understood well, so I have not 
even begun it

public Vagao pegarVagaoRemover (String nomeDoVagao){...}
}
```

This is how I have tried to create a "train" and print it in the console, but it has not worked:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Trem trem = new Trem();

  trem.adicionarVagao("qualquer");

  trem.printTrem();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`head` and `tail` are not indepedant wagons themselves.

So one should not alter head's or tail's fields in general.

Adding at the end:

```
novo_Vagao.vagaoAnterior = null;
novo_Vagao.vagaoPosterior = null;
if (head == null){
    head = tail = novo_Vagao;
} else {
    novo_Vagao.vagaoAnterior = tail;
    tail.vagaoPosterior = novo_Vago;
    tail = novo_Vagao;
}
```

Removal would go:

```
if (vagao.vagaoPosterio == null) {
    tail = vagao.vagaoAnterior;
} else {
    vagao.vagaoPosterio.vagaoAnterio = vagao.vagaoAnterior;
}
...
```

So: what *referencing* fields to change.

Comment: It did not work. There must be some problem with the exercise itself, but I thank you.